# Нужно сделать так что бы при ajax запросе вставлялся html в textarea

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

есть функция ajax запроса и див. Мне нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку с html с дива вставлялся в textarea и отправлялся ajax, как это сделать? сейчас он вставляет ,но не отправляет ничего. А если в саму текстареа записать, то он отправит

```
$('.story-publisher-box form').ajaxForm({
url: SK_source() + '?t=post&a=new',

beforeSend: function() {
    var mesA = $('.KEmoji_Input div').html();
    mesA = mesA.replace("&lt;", "<");
    mesA = mesA.replace("&gt;", ">");        
    $('.auto-grow-input').val(mesA);

    main_wrapper = $('.story-publisher-box');
    textarea = main_wrapper.find('textarea');
    inputs = main_wrapper.find('input[type="text"]');
    button = main_wrapper.find('button.submit-btn');

    button_default_text = button.find('span').text();

    textarea.attr('disabled', true);
    inputs.attr('disabled', true);
    button.attr('disabled', true);

    SK_progressIconLoader(button);
},

uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    button
        .find('span').text(percentComplete + '%');

    if (percentComplete == 100) {
        button
            .find('span').text('@processing@');
    }
},

success: function(responseText) {

    if (responseText.status == 200) {
        $('.stories-wrapper').prepend(responseText.html);
    }

    //$('.story-publisher-box form').resetForm();

    main_wrapper
        .find('.story-text-input')
        .val('')

        .end().find('.result-container')
        .remove()

        .end().find('.input-wrapper')
            .find('.result-container')
            .remove()

            .end()
            .find('.input-result-wrapper')
            .empty()

            .end().find('input')
            .show()
            .val('')

            .end().find('.remove-btn')
            .remove()

            .end().find('.youtube-link')
            .remove()
        .end().slideUp();

    textarea.removeAttr('disabled');
    inputs.removeAttr('disabled');

    button
        .removeAttr('disabled')
        .find('span').text(button_default_text);

    SK_progressIconLoader(button);
}
```

});

Comment: Собственно, не вижу чтобы вы в `value` текстового поля что-то пихали, поэтому наверно ничего и не отправляет.

Comment: Не совсем понял?

Comment: var mesA = $('.KEmoji_Input div').html();

 $('.auto-grow-input').val(mesA);

вот берем и вставляем
5 и 8 строка

Comment: Так, стоп, у вас ведь `button` становится `disabled` до отправки запроса. Может в этом проблема?

Comment: Сейчас попробовал, не получилос, убрал вообще disabled